# How to display one record from firebase in html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am trying to display one single record in HTML from firebase query, what am I doing wrong? This is the controller:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
        function (m, key, value) { vars[key] = value; });
    return vars;
}
var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
console.log("The id is: " + first);

$scope.username = CommonProp.getUser();

if (!$scope.username) {
    $location.path('/home');
}
var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://crackling-inferno-2072.firebaseio.com/Articles/" + first);
var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj.startAt($scope.username).endAt($scope.username));

$scope.title = sync.$asArray();
$scope.post = sync.$asArray();

console.log($scope.title);
console.log($scope.post);

console.log(sync);
console.log(firebaseObj);
```

I capture the id form the URL http://localhost:8000/app/#/show?id=-KHNW-LTLsOejTd-cjcO 
This is the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{post}}</p>
</div>

<h1 ng-model="article.title">{{article.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post}}</p>
```

The issue is that nothing is running, and I need to show the title and the post from that ID. Can somebody help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: Nope, it's fine according to the console.

Comment: have you included a controller?

Comment: I am thinking the problem might be in the HTML but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Sure, I have. The console shows this: `[] [] c {_config: Object, _ref: M, _arraySync: d, _objectSync: null}_arraySync: d_config: Object_objectSync: null_ref: M__proto__: Object
show.js:74 O {g: gh, path: P, w: nc, dc: false}`

Comment: So, there is no errors, it seems the array is empty but I do not know why.